# Why do visited links disable transitioning of the fill property of svg icons?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm currently using a combination of text and svg-icons as header links on my webpage, something like this:

```
<a href="google.com">
    <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M18.121,9.88l-7.832-7.836c-0.155-0.158-0.428-0.155-0.584,0L1.842,9.913c-0.262,0.263-0.073,0.705,0.292,0.705h2.069v7.042c0,0.227,0.187,0.414,0.414,0.414h3.725c0.228,0,0.414-0.188,0.414-0.414v-3.313h2.483v3.313c0,0.227,0.187,0.414,0.413,0.414h3.726c0.229,0,0.414-0.188,0.414-0.414v-7.042h2.068h0.004C18.331,10.617,18.389,10.146,18.121,9.88 M14.963,17.245h-2.896v-3.313c0-0.229-0.186-0.415-0.414-0.415H8.342c-0.228,0-0.414,0.187-0.414,0.415v3.313H5.032v-6.628h9.931V17.245z M3.133,9.79l6.864-6.868l6.867,6.868H3.133z"></path>
    </svg>
    Home
</a>
```

I'm also styling the fill property of the svg-icon when hovered, akin to this:

```
.svg-icon {
    fill: black;
    transition: fill .15s ease;
}
a:hover .svg-icon {
    fill: red;
}
```

I have included a snippet to show the issue. Timing is exaggerated to show the difference once the link has been visited: before visiting, both text and icon transition at the same speed. Afterwards, icon transitions instantaneously.
To reproduce in the snippet: hover over the link, then click it and re-run the snippet. The hover transition should change.

Could anyone explain what I'm missing? Running Safari 14.1.2.

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: fit-content;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}

.svg-icon {
  transition: fill 1s ease;
  fill: black;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

a:hover .svg-icon {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="apple.com">
  <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M18.121,9.88l-7.832-7.836c-0.155-0.158-0.428-0.155-0.584,0L1.842,9.913c-0.262,0.263-0.073,0.705,0.292,0.705h2.069v7.042c0,0.227,0.187,0.414,0.414,0.414h3.725c0.228,0,0.414-0.188,0.414-0.414v-3.313h2.483v3.313c0,0.227,0.187,0.414,0.413,0.414h3.726c0.229,0,0.414-0.188,0.414-0.414v-7.042h2.068h0.004C18.331,10.617,18.389,10.146,18.121,9.88 M14.963,17.245h-2.896v-3.313c0-0.229-0.186-0.415-0.414-0.415H8.342c-0.228,0-0.414,0.187-0.414,0.415v3.313H5.032v-6.628h9.931V17.245z M3.133,9.79l6.864-6.868l6.867,6.868H3.133z"></path>
    </svg> Home
</a>
```

Comment: This is a Safari bug, and it was very close to be a very bad one. `:visited` rule is highly dangerous for browsers as it can leak which links an user already visited. It's why you can't set properties like `transition` only on `:visited` links, because you could simply listen to the transition events and find which links have been visited. So here they were near leaking that information by doing the inverse (one could have listened to the transition events and if it didn't fire conclude that the link was visited). *But*, this is a graphic only bug, all js still sees the value transitioning...

Comment: If you do `getComputedStyle(path).fill` during the transition, you get the color it should be at that time in the transition, and all the transition events fire as expected. That was close, and I guess it's still worth telling them about it at https://bugs.webkit.org/ Unfortunately I couldn't find a simple workaround for you.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you. It seems the bug has been [reported already](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=152488), as early as 2015. However, all of the provided examples/fiddles no longer reproduce the issue. I'm new to webkit bug reporting, would it be worth submitting a new ticket?

Comment: A simple comment stating that ot still affects latest Safari on the issue might be enough